# Google sheets Regex function help needed

Tags: regex, google-sheets, regex-group

I have a DB of 600 talks on various topics by various speakers.
They are in the format of:

---

Topic 1 (Speaker 1)

Event_type_1 - , Topic 2 (Speaker 2)

Event_type_2 - , Topic 3 (Speaker 3)

Topic 4 (subtopic 1) (Speaker 1)

---

Ideally, I would want to convert the DB to the format of:

Topic 1

Topic 2

Topic 3

Topic 4 (subtopic 1)

---

Something like =REGEXEXTRACT(Cell_1,"(.+)$") would extract the text within brackets but then it would extract all brackets. Combining with IF for only (Speaker 1, Speaker 2, ... , Speaker N) is possible but clumsy.
Similarly, and IF group at the beginning for the (event_type_1, event_type_2, ... , event_type_N) is also possible but clumsy.

Feels like regex is powerful enough to enable me to do it cleaner but I'm lacking the skill. Would appreciate help and pointers!

Comment: Try `"([^,()\s][^,()]*?)\s*\("`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you! that worked but with one small imperfection: it removes all brackets within the text, whereas I'd ideally want to remove only the last set of brackets for cases like "topic 1 (important information) (speaker 1)" => "topic 1 (important information")".
I genuinely tried looking for a simple fix myself for 20 mins, but I'm too novice at regex to figure it out (I'll take proper courses soon so as to not abuse kindness of people like yourself), tyvm once again

Comment: How about `"(?:^|, )([^,]*) \("`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
([^,()\s][^,]*)\s\(
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZLvLwi/3).

*Details*:

- `([^,()\s][^,]*)` - Group 1:

  - `[^,()\s]` - a char other than `,`, `(` and `)`
  - `[^,]*` - zero or more chars other than `,`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `\(` - a `(` char.